# HTML5 or Android

Tags: android, html

I have done a bit of research on HTML5 and started doing minor programming on Android.  My questions is whether I should concentrate on HTML5 programming or Android.  I understand that with HTML5 I should be able to write once and then port for any platform(Android, iOS, BB) but only with Android that is not the case.

Any advise, suggestions, comments are welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

May I recommend a very excellent session from Google I/O 2011:

[Google I/O 2011: HTML5 versus Android: Apps or Web for Mobile Development?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4f2Zky_YyyQ)

Comment: Thanks to jBit and slandau.  I like both of your answers.  One is an hour long but I don't mind listening as it is helpful.  Unfortunately, I only can pick one answer and so I picked jBit but thanks for the comments and answers, appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

jBit's link is very good, but it's also over an hour long. By all means, watch it, it's very informational and probably better than almost any other answer you're going to get, however if you want something a little bit more summed up and quick, check out this [link](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1281).

It's from a conference in Philadelphia. Basically, the main point of the article is - you need both. HTML5 and programming for each mobile device through their native platform, each have there pros and cons, and the pipe dream of creating one "app" to run on every device the same way is by no means accessible...yet.

Answer (score 1):

Matt Gemmell wrote a [thoughtful post](http://mattgemmell.com/2011/07/22/apps-vs-the-web) about the differences between coding web apps or native apps.

Comment: Such a nice post. Thanks for directed me to there...